What food plants/algae are viable to grow 9,000 meters beneath the sea, if given plenty of light and air?
On advice from commenters, I'm rewriting this prompt to focus on the question I actually want answered.
Given an environment with a near constant temperature of 5 degrees C (41 degrees F) and possibly no pollinators, what edible plants, fungi, algae, or other crops could be expected to thrive?
The environment is a deep sea trench with artificial light and air provided. There's not much research on the effect of high pressure on plants, but what I've found suggests it's a non-factor or actually beneficial, so I'm considering that solved. Air is provided, trapped in glass bubbles where air-requiring crops will be grown; at this depth it would be toxic to animals, but I'm assuming this is again a non-problem for plants. The artificial light is provided supernaturally, and has a day/night cycle.
Commenters and posters have rightly pointed out that enough light would raise the temperature of the whole area. However, that is some really complicated math that I am not in the mood for right now (perhaps a future question). So for this question, I am assuming that it is only raising the temperature from the 4 C this location would be on Earth to the 5 C that was the cutoff point for several crops found by my preliminary research.
Given how many of these I'm ruling non-factors, in retrospect it was a mistake to focus the original question on the location of the setting; the only relevant problems are getting the crops there (beyond the scope of this question), whether they can survive the constant cold temperature, how a lack of seasons would affect their growth, and how much of a pain it would be to pollinate them.
My preliminary research says carrots, spinach, and kale are all vegetables that thrive in colder temperatures, and that Saccharina latissimi, Dulse, and Porphyra atropurpurea are all seaweeds that find 5 degrees optimal for growth (or at least can survive it, in the case of saccharina latissimi). But I'd love some more variety, especially for the terrestrial plants.

Link to a forum thread on worldbuilding the setting in general, for those curious: https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?669964-The-Shining-Depths-(WIP-Underwater-Setting)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

9000 meters is as dark as dark can be. How can there be light and not heat?

@L.Dutch Debated including this in the prompt, but light is provided by bioluminescent plankton. These are empowered nightly by a goddess of light. In short, divine intervention, but none of the gods involved have any command over heat.

@PoeticallyPsychotic If you can create arbitrarily bright light, you can create heat. Some of the light is absorbed by the things it illuminates, which heats them up.

If the plants are given plenty of light and air, why can't normal plants just grow there?

@Bobson Genuine question here. Is that not already clear from the question? It's becoming increasingly clear to me that I've screwed something up in how I've presented this one.

the pressure is a minor concern but the temprature matters a lot. 5degrees is to cold for almost any plant humans can eat.

What kind of farming setup are we dealing with here? I feel like if you have a divine light source and glass bubbles at 9000m under the ocean, a large greenhouse bubble with inside wouldn't be a stretch

@PoeticallyPsychotic - I went and read it over again, and I think I see what the confusion might be coming from.  What you're really asking is how to get around the problem of "a constant low temperature and a lack of pollinators."  Everything having to do with the fact that it's deep underwater or under high pressure is irrelevant, because you're solving the darkness, pressure (and just having water everywhere) with magical light and bubbles of air.  You'd be asking the exact same question if the setup was a sci-fi based "self-contained greenhouse on an airless moon" (1/2)

If you reframed the question to be primarily focused on the temperature and pollinators, and then just explained the magic of why the other things aren't concerns, you might get more of the type of answers you're looking for.  As-is, it reads more like a "how do I grow plants underwater" than "which plants are best for these conditions".  At least to me.  At this point it might be worth re-asking as a new question rather than editing this one, since there are already several answers.  I'm not sure what this SE's policy on that is.  (2/2)

Food Plants (and similar) That Grow In The Cold
I've been continuing to research this subject since posting the question, and have found quite a few more species that would thrive in the cold, and should thus be viable in the environment I envision.
I am, however, not a botanist, biologist, mycologist, forager, or even a gardener. If someone more knowledgeable thinks any of these wouldn't survive or grow well, or has a suggestion for a species I've missed, I'd love to hear it.
Vegetables:
When I posted this question, I had already found Kale, Spinach, and Carrots. From this site on fast-growing winter crops, here are some more that will grow at 5 degrees C (41 degrees F):

Peas
Lettuce
Radishes
Bok Choy
Possibly Mizspoona (somewhere between "not freezing" and "in the 40s")
Turnips

Fruits:
All I was able to find was the Black Diamond Apple. Not much is known about its requirements beyond that the temp. can't drop below freezing very often, and can't go above 80 F, which means it can't be mass-grown in the US. Technically, the constant ~41 F in my deep sea trench meets these requirements, but since its native habitat features wide temperature swings and also lots of UV radiation, and it doesn't produce much in the way of volume, this seems a poor choice.
Berries:
On the other hand, it turns out there are a lot of berries that grow all through the winter. Not sure how the lack of real seasons this far beneath the waves would affect their berry production, though...
Good for Foraging (viability as crops uncertain):

Nannyberries
Highbush cranberry
Barberry
Rose hips
Partridgeberry

Good for Growing:

Raspberry
Red currant
Jostaberry

Fungi:
I also found several edible fungi that thrive in cold weather, though interestingly, almost all of them prefer to grow either on or beneath trees (see next section). The same caveat for berries applies here; I have no idea how important seasonal temperature variation is to these species. An additional caveat is that I wasn’t able to find actual temperature ranges for most of these, just that they grew in winter in cold/temperate locales.

Scarlet elf cup (wood or ground, loves leaf litter)
True elm oyster mushroom (wider temperature range than other oyster mushrooms, grows on hardwood trees, especially deciduous)
Herald of winter (on ground, but beneath conifers, especially pine)
Velvet shank (dead or dying trees, especially beech or elm)
Winter chanterelle (ground in forest, near conifers or beech/birch)
Birch polypore (dead hardwood or sawdust, this is slightly outside ideal temperature, slow growth)
Witches’ butter (feeds on a parasitic tree-killing fungus, but only grows in a tree already dead)
Artist’s conk (hardwood or conifer, live or dead, perennial)
Amber jelly roll (fallen sticks/branches, thrives regardless of temperature but requires humidity/rain)
Black jelly roll (trees, often alders)
Yellowfoot chanterelle (ground, possibly require warmer temperatures)

Trees (non-fruit):
This section is potentially the most incomplete. However, dwarf white pines do seem promising.

American chestnut (absolute minimum temp for survival and growth)
Woodland chestnut (noted to be more cold-hardy than American, 3-5 years to production)
Maples (unlikely to produce syrup, as that is triggered by frost, but likely to survive; Amur maples only grow to 15-20ft tall)
River birch (cold weather, small)
White pine (tasty inner bark, edible seeds, needles apparently good for tea, average temperature in habitat is 4-10 C, sensitive to salt. Very large, but has a dwarf version only 2-7 ft tall)

Other:
I haven’t even looked at tubers and other roots; unlike many of the other edible plants, they were not neatly sorted by season in the sites I was looking at.
I already mentioned the four species of algae I believe would thrive in this temperature range, given enough light to do so: giant kelp, saccharina, dulse, and porphyra. Haven’t done any more research on this.

Special thanks to this site on fast growing winter vegetables, this site on winter mushrooms, this site on winter foraging in general, and this site on cold-region trees, all of which provided excellent starting points for my research.

Marine snow
A frame challenge. 9000 meters below the sea is dark. Pitch dark. The sunlight does not reach the bottom of the sea here, so there is nothing that can grow. At least not on sunlight.
There is very few viable life down there. That doesn't mean there isn't lofe possible. The main source of food isn't plants. It is marine snow. Marine snow is the debris of creatures and plants that has drifted out to the depths, out of reach of life thriving on sunlight.
There are still plants, just not as much as to support whole eco-systems. These plants can thrive on the marine snow, or are in polymetallic nodules, or close to thermal vents. But in the end, the greatest source of food seeded to the depths is the same. Marine snow, fed by the energy of the sun at one time, drifting into an eternal darkness.
Your society can 'farm' marine snow first, catching it on large areas, until they get some light or other energy source in abundance and get the farm to match. Without an energy source, no farming will ever produce enough to live on and form a complex society.

I don't think there are any plants at that depth. There are sessile animals that in some ways look like plants, but since they feed on the marine snow they are heterotrophs and not autotrophs, and I believe they are not related to plants.

Can you exploit thermal vents from volcanic fissures as energy and nutrient sources? They can supply both to your farmed organisms, or at least, insert a trophic level based on sulfur assimilation to enable carbon assimilation to begin. While the temperature gradient will be steep, you could implement manifolds to spread the warmth around and create more arable area. Allows for all sorts of foods, not just plants. Do you have to restrict yourself to cultivated plants or is that for convenience?
Bioluminescence isn't very bright compared to surface sunlight; to provide sufficient light for photosynthesis will be tricky without self-shading from the swarm/cloud/film of cells producing the light. Why not consume the light-producing algae directly?
A couple of links that may or may not feed off each other:
National Geographic:
https://education.nationalgeographic.org/resource/deep-sea-hydrothermal-vents/
National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration
https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/vents.html
For the chemically minded, (Zierenberg et al 2000 - slightly old but still good for an introduction) is a brief review of sulfur metabolism in high-pressure water. It also discusses issues of heat and pressure on DNA which ties into your seed storage issues: https://www.pnas.org/doi/pdf/10.1073/pnas.210395997
If you need to get sidetracked: Schramm and Weiss 2024 have a comprehensive review of bioluminescence https://chemistry-europe.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cbic.202400106

Well, there are complete ecosystems in real life around small gas vents on the ocean bottoms that are called "black smokers", so it's a good answer; but it'll be unbelieveable to have enough cracks to run a complete "farm paradise" just on them - the more cracks are in a place, the more likely that the crust would give in and a volcano would raise, destroying the farm.

The short answer is "no", because thermal vents and cold seeps occur from tectonic action on the very edges of continental plates, and undersea trenches occur very uniformly 200km from the edges of the plates. Brine pools, the other possible alternate energy source, also would not occur in deep sea trenches by current understanding of their formation.

The longer answer is that while there is a single source of that energy, from a brine 'river' flowing over the edge of the trench, it would not provide nearly enough resources to sustain a civilization.

Correction; it turns out that cold seeps do occur on the inner slope of oceanic trenches. Doesn't seem like they release the sulfide necessary for mussel growth, but perhaps something edible would still live there.

It sounds like your real concern is going to be that, at that depth, air pressure has to be much higher (unless you have entirely unreasonably strong building materials), which means that your humans are going to require that the air be a different mixture such as heliox. That, I think, could be a problem for the plants.
If so you might be able to solve this by having the agricultural domes use a different atmospheric mixture, requiring that the humans wear breathing apparatus when they enter those spaces.
But this is a guess; I honestly don't know what the air requirements are for which plants.
Upon consideration, I have to agree that adequate light does not guarantee adequate heat. Consider the efficiency of LEDs compared to incandescents, the latter produce a lot of heat but the former really don't. It may indeed be possible to produce adequate light while heating remains an issue. However, humans aren't really happy at 5C either, so your bold aquanauts are either going to be wearing heavy clothing all the time - possibly outside there personal chambers - or are going to ask you to turn up the thermostat. Similarly, you might want to heat the growing containers in your agricultural space, to permit growing plants which have similar objections. This is sounding like you really want to do a full energetic evaluation of the space, determine what your real power requirements are, how you are going to meet them, and what trade-offs you can make to simplify that. You probably don't want to try growing anything that requires tropical conditions but your options may be wider than you are assuming.

Heat doesn't get used up, the way light does. It gets lost. But ludicrous quantities of insulation can help reduce heat losses to an acceptable level, for arbitrary values of "acceptable".

Fortunately, the sapient species in this environ isn't humans. Well, not anymore. Their bodies are perfectly adapted for the deepest depths... but there just isn't enough food down there for all of them, hence the need for farming.

This paper will shed some light on the topic ... it does require, shall we say, some interpretation.  But I think they're saying that around 100 atm of pressure stops most of the root growth and even more of the chlorophyll growth for some plants tested, and that's only 1 km depth equivalent.

Underwater fungi
If you would call an entity that's using photosynthesis as a means to produce energy for its life a plant, there won't be enough energy reaching that deep for any meaningful photosynthesis to work, as the only light sources down there are either bottom cracks that have lava/magma on the other side, or any animal/plant luminence designed to attract prey (say angler fish). This is not enough to recover enough energy from to support any life.
But, there is a steady influx of dead bodies going down, be it whales or plankton, small fish or medusas, photic zone algae or washed in wood; all of them contain leftover energy that can feed entities that act as decomposers, retrieving energy from whatever high order molecules contained in their food as a means to support its life and grow. Most of them are qualified as fungi (molds, mushrooms, that stuff). They act slowly, as the supply is highly irregular, they can live for hundreds of years over a single big whale carcass and release enough spores to ensure that the next one would also be eaten by them eventually, they might be a food source for whatever animal life existing at those depths, thus they won't grow big enough to be noticeable.
Still, you might assume that some species of fungus have evolved to form mushroom-like structures that periodically appear on the bottom to release the spores and then are eaten or rot away, like those "puffball" mushrooms above the ground, varying in size, shape and longevity. Although I'm not aware of what is the landscape down there, but coloring it slightly by letting some of them emanate a little light for whatever evolutionary reason (parasitic spores? intermediate host? maturity inside animals? symbiosis? you design) would add some spice to the world you're building.
Since you are desigining a farm, you can effectively build a farm of fungi alike those that grow champignons above the ground. Just find a human-edible fungus out of those that might grow down there, and cultivate it by adding nutrients to the ocean soil, and collect the shrooms as they grow.

Ah, fungi, another kingdom of life I had somehow forgotten as a possible food source. I imagine some of these deep-sea fungi would adapt to an influx of algae and plants as new food sources, and could then be cultivated as food themselves.
